# How to reset MySQL root password in OSX? Popular method does not work

Tags: mysql, macos

I cannot login as `root@localhost` in MySQL.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried the following method which I suppose most of the users would have heard of:

1. stop mysql
2. mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
3. login as mysql -u root
4. UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
5. FLUSH PRIVILEGES
6. quit

This won't work. Is there any other suggestion?

After I login in step 3, when I　`SELECT * FROM mysql.user`, the result is empty. It seems that there is no root user.

OS: OS Yosemite. I use the MySQL comes natively with the Macbook Pro.

The problem seems to occur when I try to change the connecting socket from `/tmp/mysql.sock` to `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Thank you very much.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: After step 3 try running the command `use mysql`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have updated some additional points.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following command's work on my MySQL installation in Yosemite.

1. Stop MySQL
2. `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. login as `mysql -u root`
4. `use mysql;`
5. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';`
6. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
7. Quit MySQL and restart as normal

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is not working also. What is the significance of the extra step 4?

Comment: Step 4 means that you select the `mysql` database for future queries (against tables).

Answer (score 0):

you could try `mysql_install_db` in the terminal , this will create system tables and should restore root password to default which is nothing. see if it has any other implications that affects you [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-install-db.html).